# CouchDB and validate_doc_read function

Tags: authorization, couchdb

#### The problem:

CouchDB has not be designed to support per-document read-control.

#### As a proposed solution:

Create **Validate_doc_read** function (javascript function be called on every read, in the same manner as the validate_doc_update system is applied).

In **_users database** I defined function inside the document like this:

```
"validate_doc_read": "function(doc, userCtx) {
    if ((typeof doc.name !== 'undefined') && (doc.name != userCtx.name)) {
        throw({unauthorized: userCtx.name + ' cannnot read ' + doc._id});
    }"
}
```

But the function does not work Why?

Comment: Is the "validate_doc_read" function fully valid?  It appears to be missing a closing curly-brace.

Comment: Thank you for your note, I have added the missing brace.. but still does not work

Answer (score 1):

validate_doc_read is not supported by CouchDB. Only validate_doc_update function is supported.

Per-document read permission is not supported in CouchDB

Comment: I know per-document read permission is not supported in CouchDB, I try to make it by using Validate_doc_read.. is there any idea to implement per-document read permission

Comment: Database per user pattern is the recommended aproach for read access restrictions. You can find a proposal for include this functionallity in future versions: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/blob/a0cfaead837dfe0199fb42214d43ced2778cc410/rfcs/010-per-document-access-control.md